What is the plant being grown in this video, is it spinach? What kind of spinach?

This looks like mature spinach to me, or is it something else?

I think the family is correct. It may be also some sort of beets/chards. On the photo, I get the impression they are larger then spinach, but it can be just an impression because of lack of references.

there is no video

I think the photo is showing a variety of spinach. It appears to be similar to this heirloom called Bloomsdale Long Standing or the newer Space varieties.
